# DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `info', in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I am trying to add pdf generation through Prawn to my Rails 3 app. I am following the Railscast and all was going well until I try to pass an instance variable from my controller to a separate class I created.

The controller action looks like this:

```
def show #shows some material
@material = Material.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    pdf = MaterialPdf.new(@material)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "material_#{@material.id}.pdf", 
                          type: "application/pdf",
                          disposition: "inline"
  end
end
```

end

and the material_pdf.rb file looks like this:

```
class MaterialPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(material)
    super
    @material = material
    text "Placeholder text"
  end
end
```

The error message I'm getting from the log is weird:

```
Material Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "materials".* FROM "materials" WHERE "materials"."id" = ? ORDER BY materials.created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "27"]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `info'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer` etc. (called from initialize at .../app/pdfs/material_pdf.rb:3)
```

It's odd because the query looks fine and I'm NOT trying to create an attribute 'info'. I don't get it. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's prawn that's trying to create that attribute:

http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html

I think explains it better:

[Deprecation warning for creating attribute 'currency'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596073/deprecation-warning-for-creating-attribute-currency)

Anyway, I think you're you're actually calling super incorrectly. Document.new takes a an options hash:

```
def initialize(options={},&block)
```

So you need to pass that, not the material instance to the superclass:

```
class MaterialPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(material, prawn_opts = {})
    super(prawn_opts)
    @material = material
    text "Placeholder text"
  end
end
```