# Best Way to Create attributes for a Model Instance Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm building a Rails server for the back-end of an iPhone app. Rails sends JSON to the front-end and I find myself doing something like this.

```
@user = User.find(1)

@user["status"] = "Some cool status"

render :json => @user.to_json
```

In my rspec tests I get

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `status'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer` etc.
```

I find it hard to find an appropriate alternative when it's just as easy to write an key value to the object that will be  sent to the iPhone.

My question is what are some viable alternatives to what I'm trying to do and what's specially "wrong" with my code, besides the deprecation.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `attr_accessor`?

Comment: Sometimes I may have the attribute set to an unique name or I'll use this technique on rare occasions. I'm not sure how conventional it is to go with this method, hence why I'm asking.

Comment: As the deprecation states, this isn't going to be supported - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596073/deprecation-warning-for-creating-attribute-currency

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware. But it's just nice to have without writing a back end component to it since it's something that is arbitrarily used and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `User` object to hash and then mix additional keys to it:

```
class User
    def to_hash
        hash = {}
        instance_variables.each {|var| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = instance_variable_get(var) }
        hash
    end
end
```

And in your controller:

```
user = User.find(1)

user = user.to_hash

user[:status] = "Some cool status"

render :json => user.to_json
```

PS. No need to use instance variable `@user` as you render json anyway, local `user` variable is good enough.

Comment: Hmm. My user returns as `{"attributes"=>{}, "relation"=>nil, "changed_attributes"=>{}, "previously_changed"=>{}, "attributes_cache"=>{}, "association_cache"=>{}, "aggregation_cache"=>{}, "marked_for_destruction"=>false, "destroyed"=>false, "readonly"=>false, "new_record"=>false} `

Comment: It is because your `User` is ActiveRecord model. You can specify which instance attributes should be converted to json in this way:
`user.attributes.to_json(:only => ['first_name','last_name'])`

Comment: another solution is just to write out a hash and do a .to_json on it esp if the data you will be sending back is small